# Cant import rewire module

Tags: javascript, require

I'm trying to use rewire module: https://github.com/jhnns/rewire 
But can't import it. 
 
I am using windows 10.

I install rewire with:

```
npm install rewire
```

And I check it installed properly with:

```
npm list
```

Outputs:

```
+-- rewire@2.5.2
```

Failed attempt #1:

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
// Error: Module name "rewire" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Failed attempt #2:

```
require(['rewire'], function (rewire) {

});
// Error: rewire.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I know the REQUIRE library is working because I can do:

```
var module = require(["tests/temp"]); // works fine
```

I tried to find some kind of rewire.js source file, but I don't think it works that way

How can I use REWIRE library?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you:
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: The syntax in your failed attempt #2 is correct, I'm guessing it's a path problem. Is the rewire.js file located in the same directory as the module that you're trying to load it from?

Comment: I dont have a rewire.js file, I'm not sure if I need it, or even where to get it. I can't find such a rewire.js file on the github or anywhere. In all tutorials I haven't seen anyone mention or download a rewire.js file, they just include it and it works